# What does 'info do?

Tags: anchor, solana-program, rust, lifetimes

Here is the typical rust-solana program example below. I understand everything what happens there, but `'info` not really. Although it looks like lifetime annotation I have doubts, is it? What is its functionality/role?

```
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;

declare_id!("Fg6PaFpoGXkYsidMpWTK6W2BeZ7FEfcYkg476zPFsLnS");

#[program]
mod puppet {
    use super::*;
    pub fn init(_ctx: Context<Init>) -> Result<()> {
        Ok(())
    }
    pub fn set_data(ctx: Context<SetData>, data: u64) -> Result<()> {
        let puppet = &mut ctx.accounts.puppet;
        puppet.data = data;
        Ok(())
    }
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Init<'info> {
    #[account(init, payer = user, space = 8 + 8 )]
    pub puppet: Account<'info, Data>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub user: Signer<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct SetData<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub puppet: Account<'info, Data>
}

#[account]
pub struct Data {
    pub data: u64
}
```

Comment: It is a lifetime construct. It's used to ensure that all borrows are valid.

Comment: Oh, it's much simpler than I thought))
Thanks for your answer!